# Consecutive quadratic residues.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I am stuck with the following question given to us in an assignment:

Let $p>5$ be prime.Let $S=\{1,2,...,p-1\}$

Show that at least one of $2,5,10$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

Hence show that there exists two consecutive integers in $S$,both of which are quadratic residues mod $p$.

Use the previous result to show that there exists two consecutive integers in $S$,both of which are quadratic non-residues mod $p$.

I have done the proof of the first one.$(\frac{2}{p})(\frac{5}{p})=(\frac{10}{p})$ and all of them cannot be $-1$ as we will get $1=-1$ which is a contradiction.

But,I am not sure how to prove the next two results.I have tried in the following way:

For all $a\in S$,$(\frac{a}{p})(\frac{a+1}{p})=(\frac{a(a+1)}{p})$.Let us suppose that there does not exist two consecutive integers in $S$ such that both of them are quadratic residues mod $p$.Then LHS is $-1$.But then I am stuck and I could not prove the third part also.Can someone show me a way out?

Comment: For the second part, think about one, four, and nine.

Comment: For the third part, think about how many quadratic residues/non-residues there are (and what must happen for nonresidues, if there are consecutive residues)